# Flux optimistic updates handled by the library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux, reactjs-flux

Is there some flux library that handles optimistic updates for you? I've heard that Relay library can do that, but it only works with a graphql server (which I don't have).

I would love to use a library that will handle all the flux and optimistic updates logic for me so that I don't have to write it myself.

Comment: I actually just found https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/redux-optimist, which adds that functionality to a reducer.

Comment: I just found another library for optimistic updates with redux, https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/redux-optimist